# Is it possible to use a sort of constant or a custom token in the rewrite section of a views field?

Tags: views, tokens

My use case.

I have a portion of a URL of another site (www.example1.com) under each of my nodes (let's say node type B).

Each of these nodes can be related with another node (let's say node type A).

I need a view which show informations of A nodes and get the URL portions from B nodes using the relationship section of the view.

That's ok, I get what I want but I would like to create a URL with this URL's portion adding a constant/token at the beginning (www.example1.com) so that it can changed in a simple way (let's say www.example2.com) instead of modify each field of the view.

My best bet should be probably to rewrite the template of the view and using a constant (variable_get/set should be fine) but I would like to have this field configurable with the UI.

Thanks

Comment: does the view show the correct fields (via the relationship) that hold the information you want to present in the link? If so, creating a customized link field should be simple.

Comment: yes, my problem is only focused on how to use a constant or a token or whatsoever variable which can later be changed without changing the view.
Think that: you put [my-custom-token]/path1 in the rewrite output of one field, [my-custom-token]/path2 in a second field, [my-custom-token]/pathN in the n-th field.
If [my-custom-token] is externally configurable, you can have:
[my-custom-token] = "http://www.myexternalurl1.com" and then you easily change it "http://www.myexternalurl2.com" if you want (that's exactly my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you can either use a hidden field on a node to create a node specific value which you can rewrite as a link if desired, or create a Global:Custom Text where you can include whatever static or variable data you desire, so long as the fields containing the information are present (visible or not).

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I create an hidden "Global: Custom Text" with value "www.example1.com" and then I use this value on the rewrite output of the fields that I need to rewrite, I can solve this problem. Then, if I need to change "www.example1.com" into "www.example2.com" instead of changing each field I can just change the value of the "Global: Custom Text" field. Thanks.